Is there an API for chess-results.com
TL;DR: Does the website chess-results.com have an API?
Long version:
I'm working on something that needs some information about tournaments and games that reside on chess-results.com.
I could use a proper API (readonly is enough) so I would not scrape different pages and parse & process HTML. Mostly since the tournaments have different formats and, depending on this, they are displayed differently on the website.
I know that there are some excel files that can be downloaded and parsed, since they are a little more structured than the HTML pages, but I could use something more reliable.


Does the website chess-results.com have an API?

No.
The chess-results.com website is a key selling point for the Swiss Manager pairing program. If you buy the program then you get the right to upload your tournaments to chess-results. It's function is to provide an additional service to Swiss Manager owners not to provide a service to data collectors.
Heinz Herzog is the developer. If you would be willing to pay for an API then you could make him a business offer.

I'm working on something that needs some information about tournaments and games that reside on chess-results.com

Be warned that "tournaments" on chess-results are not necessarily genuine tournaments with real players. Swiss Manager owners are encouraged as part of their learning process to construct dummy tournaments with fictitious players which they can upload to chess-results to see how it all works.

Thank you for your answer, not what I was hoping for, but it's something. I am willing to pay for an API, but more like a subscription not to build it for me only. For the record, I was trying to use it for real tournaments organized by the Romanian Chess Federation only, not for collecting data, but that's not really important.. Thank you again.
